# Laravel Xero The consumer was denied access to this resource

Tags: laravel, xero-api

Xero Public API

**Laravel 5.6**

Continue to receive the following error call after approving access for Xero (my app name) to access my demo company in Xero. It returns with an oauth_token, oauth_verifier and org query parameters but fails when trying to hit the request in the gist below on line 74

https://gist.github.com/seivad/a54901974ec4064f8fe6665e11a86598

I can't find anything on their API site to advise what to do next...

Answer (score 1):

Can I assume you're using the [calcinai/xero-php](https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php/blob/master/examples/public.php) library?

The only things I can think of here to check are:

1. You're using the Public Application client. Is the [app you've setup](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/api-application-types) in Xero a Public Application, or a Private One?
2. Are the services.config settings setup correctly to match your app credentials, and your callback domain that you are testing with?
3. Is your session definitely persisting with the correct tokens? (might be worth seeing what the output of your session()->get() calls are on lines 67 and 68

For what it is worth, the oauth error descriptions for Xero are outlined here, but I don't see your one: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/auth-and-limits/oauth-issues